# Using Multi-page template by jquery mobile to display search result

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Here is my Html code. What I am trying sounds simple but I am not able to do so. I am trying to use Multi page template as suggest by jquery mobile. First page I have a text box and button. User enters a value in text box and then clicks the button which should take the user to "page2" and show the search details.

My code below is taking me to "page2" but I am not able to see any search results. I inserted an alert in between and that pops up with the data. Also the back button on page2 doesn't take me to page1?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Employee Finder</title>

    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"/>
    <script src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"/> 
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"/>
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script> 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#findemplyoee').click(function() {

          $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reverse: true });

             var employeeNumber = $("#employeeNumber").val();
             var employeedetail = JSON.parse(... call a function here);

             if(employeedetail.found)
             {
                     $('#employeefirstName').text(employeedetail.firstName);
                     $('#employeelastName').text(employeedetail.lastName);
             }
             else
             {
                     $('#employeeDetails').html("<p>Sorry the employee Number you entered was not found!</p>");
             }

        });
    });

    </script>

    </head> 
    <body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Find Employee Data</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="searchDetails">    
           <input name="employeeNumber" type="text" id="employeeNumber"/>
           <input type="button" id="findemplyoee" data-theme="b" value="Find Employee"/>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Two</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="employeeDetails">
           <p id="employeefirstName"></p>
           <p id="employeelastName"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to jQuery Mobile 1.1!
Your example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eUTga/

I am pretty sure that your included jQuery version (jquery-mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min.js) is not well tested with the old jQuery Mobile (jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js) - or simply incompatible.

Note that the jQuery Mobile team recommends to use jQuery 1.6.4 with the latest stable (1.1.0) on the jQM download site (http://jquerymobile.com/download/).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! That did work so it was a version issue. I teste your jsfiddle solution and works great. Let me try this into my local. Thanks very much "hna"

Comment: Yep! Just tested and it worked flawlessly. You made my day "hna". Thanks again.